# install rosserial on ROS Kinetic Help

Tags: rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Is there any solution to install rosserial on ros kinetic please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237204/install-rosserial-on-ros-kinetic-help/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install it from source from [Github](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial).  There is a jade branch which will work.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-06-16**:
I already try with git clone but when i run catkin_make i receive error.
Did you mean like that?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2016-06-16**:
Yes, I did.  Include the error in your question.

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-06-16**:
I will add the error after i dont have raspberry know.
Can you give me commands which you used?

**Comment by [vmatos](https://answers.ros.org/users/17756/vmatos/) on 2016-07-07**:
Commands can be found on another answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/236351/rosserial-on-ros-kinetic/?answer=236352#post-id-236352

Edit the question to include all your steps and errors you obtain.